# flutter [Instance of 'Data', Instance of 'Data']

Tags: flutter

I am trying to get filtered data from api, i have 3 categories in api 1)Ongoing 2)Upcoming and 3)Past. i want to filter all three categories on click event of diff diff buttons. Please find below mentioned code and detail.

Following are the response of api:

```
{
  "status": true,
  "result": "found",
  "data": [
    {
      "ref_id": "73",
      "postId": "106764933065187174744",
      "azakhana_name": "sakina baugh",
      "city_name": "rajula",
      "description": "djsjjsje",
      "end_date": "31-01-2023",
      "image_path": "Posts_Images\/POST-IMG106843982.jpg",
      "name_of_schollar": "Yasin Rajani",
      "postDateTime": "19-01-2023 12:22 PM",
      "program_list": "Majlis",
      "special_notes": "bsjsisjs",
      "start_date": "31-01-2023",
      "time": "3:30 PM",
      "user_name": "Taki Rajani",
      "status": "Upcoming"
    },
    {
      "ref_id": "71",
      "postId": "106764933065187174744",
      "azakhana_name": "Shanti baugh",
      "city_name": "Mahuva",
      "description": "No",
      "end_date": "31-01-2023",
      "image_path": "Posts_Images\/POST-IMG471193454.jpg",
      "name_of_schollar": "Molana ",
      "postDateTime": "18-01-2023 12:28 PM",
      "program_list": "Majlis",
      "special_notes": "No",
      "start_date": "18-01-2023",
      "time": "12:28 PM",
      "user_name": "Taki Rajani",
      "status": "Ongoing"
    },
    {
      "ref_id": "72",
      "postId": "106764933065187174744",
      "azakhana_name": "hussiani hall ",
      "city_name": "Mahuva ",
      "description": "jsjsisjw",
      "end_date": "31-01-2023",
      "image_path": "Posts_Images\/POST-IMG1564452985.jpg",
      "name_of_schollar": "yes soon",
      "postDateTime": "19-01-2023 12:21 PM",
      "program_list": "Majlis",
      "special_notes": "sjsis8sisjsj",
      "start_date": "17-01-2023",
      "time": "12:20 PM",
      "user_name": "Taki Rajani",
      "status": "Ongoing"
    }
  ],
  "totalPosts": "3",
  "totalPages": 1,
  "perPageLimit": 3,
  "currentPage": 1,
  "hasNextPage": 0
}
```

I have one button in my app which name is data filter.
I am using where method for filtering data from api but its give me error like instance of data.

Following code for filter data:

```
var _status = snapshot.data!.data!.where((e) => e.status == "Upcoming").toList();
print(_status);
```

**error : I/flutter (21212): [Instance of 'Data', Instance of 'Data']**

Comment: you must use "await"

Comment: where i can add "await" ? @A.Sang

Comment: func() async{
....
var _status = await snapshot....
return _status;
}

Comment: print with for loop.

Comment: ok, i am new in flutter so sir can you please tell this function how print in for loop?@A.Sang

Comment: @TakiRajani I think you might need to have some read about Futures in Dart before...
https://medium.flutterdevs.com/explore-futures-in-flutter-50ea5b91fc2
https://api.dart.dev/be/175791/dart-async/Future-class.html

Comment: Why do you think that's an error? It looks like you've printed a list containing two `Data` instances. If you want the output to be more meaningful, override `toString` in `Data`

Comment: 'toString' method gives me output '[]'.@RichardHeap

Comment: show more code to get correct answer.

Comment: 'var _status = snapshot.data!.data!.where((e) =>  e.status == "Upcoming").toList();
                                      print("dmeo////////////////////");
                                      List<Data> toString() {
                                        return _status;
                                      }
                                      print(_status);' @A.Sang

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert';
Future<void> main() async {
  var body = await getData();
  var _status = body['data'].where((e) => e['status'] == "Upcoming").toList();

  for (var element in _status) {
    print(element);
  }
}

// for demo usage of future, async and await. Or api call.
Future getData() async {
   String jsons = await '''{
    "status": true,
    "result": "found",
    "data": [
      {
        "ref_id": "73",
        "postId": "106764933065187174744",
        "azakhana_name": "sakina baugh",
        "city_name": "rajula",
        "description": "djsjjsje",
        "end_date": "31-01-2023",
        "image_path": "Posts_Images\/POST-IMG106843982.jpg",
        "name_of_schollar": "Yasin Rajani",
        "postDateTime": "19-01-2023 12:22 PM",
        "program_list": "Majlis",
        "special_notes": "bsjsisjs",
        "start_date": "31-01-2023",
        "time": "3:30 PM",
        "user_name": "Taki Rajani",
        "status": "Upcoming"
      },
      {
        "ref_id": "71",
        "postId": "106764933065187174744",
        "azakhana_name": "Shanti baugh",
        "city_name": "Mahuva",
        "description": "No",
        "end_date": "31-01-2023",
        "image_path": "Posts_Images\/POST-IMG471193454.jpg",
        "name_of_schollar": "Molana ",
        "postDateTime": "18-01-2023 12:28 PM",
        "program_list": "Majlis",
        "special_notes": "No",
        "start_date": "18-01-2023",
        "time": "12:28 PM",
        "user_name": "Taki Rajani",
        "status": "Ongoing"
      },
      {
        "ref_id": "72",
        "postId": "106764933065187174744",
        "azakhana_name": "hussiani hall ",
        "city_name": "Mahuva ",
        "description": "jsjsisjw",
        "end_date": "31-01-2023",
        "image_path": "Posts_Images\/POST-IMG1564452985.jpg",
        "name_of_schollar": "yes soon",
        "postDateTime": "19-01-2023 12:21 PM",
        "program_list": "Majlis",
        "special_notes": "sjsis8sisjsj",
        "start_date": "17-01-2023",
        "time": "12:20 PM",
        "user_name": "Taki Rajani",
        "status": "Ongoing"
      }
    ],
    "totalPosts": "3",
    "totalPages": 1,
    "perPageLimit": 3,
    "currentPage": 1,
    "hasNextPage": 0
  }''';
  final body = json.decode(jsons);
  return body;
}
```

Comment: actually, i am trying fetch this data inside a stram builder so how to manage this code? basically i want to do filter in my list view with data. so any other way to write code?